# Typescript Failing in Travis Build

Tags: typescript, continuous-integration, travis-ci, tsc, tsd

I am trying to get my project to build on Travis (all works fine locally). I am running into an issue with Typescript. In my `.travis.yml` file, I ahve this group of commands:

```
before_script:
  - npm i -g typescript typings
  - typings install
  - tsc
```

to run the typescript compilation. However, when I run this, I get loads of errors...

e.g.

> client/dev/nav/nav.component.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../user/services/user.service'.
>   node_modules/angular2-jwt/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(35,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angular2-jwt/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(50,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angular2-jwt/node_modules/rxjs/CoreOperators.d.ts(89,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

[Here](https://travis-ci.org/georgeedwards/Gen-App/builds/120477747) is the full build log. and [Here](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Gen-App) is the full repo.

Presumably, Typings is not installed correctly, Typings is not configured correctly or There's no reference to the main typings file in any server/client files?

Would really appreciate some guidance as to what might be wrong, or where I can look to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

> Typings is not configured correctly

From the error log `Promise` is not defined. Quickest fix is to just add `promise.d.ts` e.g. : [v8promise.d.ts](https://github.com/alm-tools/alm/blob/965c9cdca37c96096acb7c8d4a42036019fe9b01/src/typings/v8promise.d.ts) and add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

use Jasmine's promises instead

```
import { promise } from 'protractor'
```